# Which version of Angular should I learn?

Tags: angular

I am having a hard time selecting the version of Angular. Currently, lots of tutorials on YouTube in which they have been using 6 but now 8 is released. Very few were using 7.

Answer (score 2):

learn the latest from their official doc (tutorial ) and all other things you can easily find in their documentation

https://angular.io/docs